# ¿Cómo implemento un IF en un UPDATE?

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando actualizar los datos de una columna, tomando como referencia 
 un intervalo de fechas, pero me resultan error de sintaxis, sospecho que es por la estructura CASE inconclusa al final.

```
 UPDATE pagos 

 SET estado_pago = 'Próximo por Pagar' = CASE
        WHEN status_pago = 'Activo' 
       AND estado_pago = 'Pendiente' 
       AND fechatope_pago <= '" & fecha_contador & "'
       AND fechatope_pago >= '" & Today & "'
       ELSE NULL-// En esta linea me da error
       END      -// En esta linea me da error 


SET estado_pago = 'Demorado' = CASE 
       WHEN status_pago = 'Activo'
       AND estado_pago <> 'Pagado'
       AND estado_pago <> 'Completo'
       AND fechatope_pago <= '" & fecha_contador & "'
       AND fechatope_pago >= '" & Today & "'
 ELSE NULL
 END
```

Comment: y si.. no veo nada de ese Query que sea valido.. es mas esta totalmente incompleto. Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No se entiende bien qué quieres hacer, explícate mejor. Y el error te está dando porque tienes 2 ELSE y ningun IF.... Ahh! también te sobra la etiqueta "vb.net". Saludos

Comment: Lo de `SET estado_pago = 'Próximo por Pagar' = CASE` es incorrecto. Mira [un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14893412/1983854): `UPDATE prices
SET final_price= CASE
   WHEN currency=1 THEN 0.81*final_price
   ELSE final_price
END`

Answer (score 3):

Cuando haces un `CASE` no pones nada antes, simplemente haz el `SET estado_pago = CASE ...` y entonces haces tus validaciones:

```
UPDATE pagos SET estado_pago = CASE
        WHEN status_pago = 'Activo' 
            AND estado_pago = 'Pendiente' 
            AND fechatope_pago <= '" & fecha_contador & "'
            AND fechatope_pago >= '" & Today & "'
        THEN 'Próximo por Pagar'
        WHEN status_pago = 'Activo'
            AND estado_pago <> 'Pagado'
            AND estado_pago <> 'Completo'
            AND fechatope_pago <= '" & fecha_contador & "'
            AND fechatope_pago >= '" & Today & "'
        THEN 'Demorado'
        ELSE NULL
    END
 WHERE ...
```

Cada posible caso es un `WHEN` y el valor a escribir está descrito en `THEN`; el último caso que es cuando no se haya cumplido ninguna de las condiciones es lo único que escribes en el `ELSE`. Por último, **¡no olvides el `WHERE`!**

Te dejo unos enlaces para que veas los ejemplos:

- http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html
- https://codigoayuda.wordpress.com/2011/02/28/mysql-select-case-example/
- http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/13/inline-if-and-case-statements-in-mysql/